# I want to update form data in Node.js, but whenever i run this code it sets all the values to null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.put('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
//new actor data
var actor = {
    'name': req.body.name,
    'dob': req.body.dob,
    'photo': req.file,
    'bio' : req.body.bio
};

 //updating actor
Actor.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:req.params.id }, { $set: actor }, { new: true }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({
            status: false,
            error: err
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            status: true,
            data: data
        });
    }

});
});
```

I have tried it with post also and taking id through body also but still it is not working.
Tried it on postman as well as on frontend through form also. In postman also it is not able to take data or read data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in order to update the actor :

```
Actor.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:req.params.id }, {$set: {actor:actor},}, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    res.send({
        status: false,
        error: err
    });
} else {
    res.send({
        status: true,
        data: data
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Thank, but i configured it out by myself.    I needed to use upload.single('photo') in parameters of app.put

Comment: So, did you solve it by yourself? Glad to hear that :)